# Why ~ operator returns -1 for a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, operators

`~(function () {}).toString();` is absolutely valid JavaScript syntax and I saw that it returns `-1`.

I know that `~` is not operator. For instance `~5`=`~0101` which means `1010` in base 2 and `10` in decimal.

```js
console.log(~(function () {}).toString());
```

But what is the explanation in this situation ?

Maybe `~NaN` returns `-1`.

Comment: Explanation: https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Comment: This the same if you'll try to do this with `NaN` like so `~(NaN)` it will give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bitwise-not-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> Let oldValue be ToInt32(GetValue(expr)).

`Number((function () {}).toString();)` -> `Number("function () {}")` -> `NaN`

Again as per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32)

> If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.

so `~NaN` amounts to `~0` which is **-1**

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this blog: **The Great Mystery of the Tilde(~)**](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/):

The tilde is an operator that does something that you’d normally think wouldn’t have any purpose. It is a unary operator that takes the expression to its right performs this small algorithm on it (where `N` is the expression to the right of the tilde): `-(N+1)`. See below for some samples.

```
console.log(~-2); //  1
console.log(~-1); //  0
console.log(~0);  // -1
console.log(~1);  // -2
console.log(~2);  // -3
```